# Find the maximum number of consecutive zeros in an array

Tags: java

> **Question:** To find the maximum number of consecutive zeros in a given
>   array.
>
> **Example:**
>
> **Input:** \${1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0}\$
>
> **Output:** "Maximum number of consecutive zeros : 6"

Here is what I've come up with:

```
public class ZeroSeriesLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = {1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0};

        int maxLength = 0;
        int tempLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            if (values[i] == 0) {
                tempLength++;
            } else {
                tempLength = 0;
            }

            if (tempLength > maxLength) {
                maxLength = tempLength;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Maximum number of consecutive zeros : " + maxLength);
    }
}
```

Is the logic correct? Or can it be done via a simple approach?

Comment: Suggestion, put `if (tempLength > maxLength) { maxLength = tempLength; }` in the else statement.

Comment: @NPSF3000 I think that would be rather premature optimization... It doesn't give much with a reasonable amount of Items and a good branch-prediction algorithm.

Comment: @Vogel612 True, and if you don't put another one after the loop you could miss the last length.

Comment: You could put it right after tempLength++.  It's probably fine where it is though.

Comment: Algorithm is absolutely fine. Quite straightforward, easy to see that it is correct, performance close to optimal. Unless you have evidence that its performance is critical, it can stay as it is. You'd probably want to turn the algorithm into a function for reuse. Looking at the comments above, you see how trying to optimise speed can lead to subtle problems if you don't watch out.

Comment: The algorithm is actually quite identical to RLE (run length encoding) minus the output from it (RLE is usually *60, meaning 6 0's replace the "*60"). I would personally turn it into a method, and then be able to change the number you are taking into account.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting task. If you know link source with similar task please give me it. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just a few short comments on your code:

#### Separation of concerns:

You should separate functionality into different parts. Currently your main method does everything. For small applications like this, that may not be a problem, but as soon as you have larger applications, it becomes more and more unpractical.

You should thus extract your "logic" into a method:

```
private static int countSuccessiveZeros(int[] values) {
   int maxLength = 0;
   int tempLength = 0;
   //....
   // Looping here
   return maxLength;
}
```

Now if you wanted to not count zeros, but twos, you could simply modify the code to the following:

```
private static int countSuccessive(int[] values, int target) {
   int maxLength = 0;
   int tempLength = 0;
   //Your loop here, instead of 0 use target to compare
   return maxLength;
}
```

This also makes your main-method more readable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] values = {1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0};
   int successiveZeros = countSuccessive(values, 0);
   System.out.println("Maximum number of consecutive zeros : " + successiveZeros);
}
```

#### Naming:

Very nice, a compliment. Your variable names are short, clear, descriptive and follow Java conventions (`camelCase`). Keep it up ;)

Answer (score 6):

Keeping in mind of @Vogel612's nice answer (which is completly true), I have 2 more points to make.

A for-each loop is easier than a normal for loop. Don't worry about the correct order, it's the same as the order you have in the "standard" for loop.

Secondly, I would move the `if (values[i] == 0)` to a ternary statement.
You have an if-else statement that sets the same integer.

The second if statement is in my opinion great. Simple check and if true set the value.

So my solution is:

```
 public static int countSuccessiveb (int[] values, int target) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    int tempLength = 0;

    for (int value : values) {
        tempLength = (value == target) ? 1 + tempLength : 0;
        if (tempLength > maxLength) {
            maxLength = tempLength;
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: `tempLength = ++tempLength` is weird, since the `++` operator already performs an assignment. It takes me a minute to convince myself that it works.

Comment: @200_success but it works or not :)

Comment: It works, but `tempLength = (value == target) ? 1 + tempLength : 0` would have been better. Same number of symbols, ignoring whitespace.

Comment: @chillworld The original code works as well. The point of code review to produce **better** code. FYI, I would put some whitespace in that ternary. Probably a newline after the ?, and after the : such that tempLength and 0 line up.

Comment: @200_success your right, I'll edit it

Answer (score 3):

In the addendum to aforesaid :

1 . The comparation (tempLength > maxLength) should be moved to the first if block. If current is not zero, then tempLength is obviously not greater than maxLength, and therefore comparation is useless waste of CPU time.

```
       if (values[i] == 0) {
          if (++tempLength > maxLength) {
                maxLength = tempLength;
          }

       } else {
                tempLength = 0;
       }
```

2 . The comparation and assignment of maxLength could be reduced to:

```
maxLength = tempLength > maxLength?tempLength : maxLength; 

//or

maxLength = Math.max(maxLength,tempLength);
```

3 . Inline incrementation of tempLength :

```
maxLength = Math.max(maxLength,++tempLength);
```

So you code may look just like:

```
    public class ZeroSeriesLength {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0};

        int maxLength = 0;
        int tempLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            if (values[i] == 0) {
                maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, ++tempLength);
            } else {
                tempLength = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Maximum number of consecutive zeros : " + maxLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the inline incrementation of `tempLength` is difficult to spot and thus maybe a little problematic... Either way, nice point on the if-statement +1

Comment: The logic is certainly cleaner this way. However, with `Math.max()`, I wouldn't claim that it saves CPU cycles.

Comment: I don't think you will win (much) by refactoring the if-statement to the Math.Max

Answer (score 3):

Why count every time all zero?  Just look if this index is the first zero, then check if `index + max_zero_strike + 1 == 0`.  If true, check the value before and after. That way you may be a bit more efficient.

big edit: trying to make the code work, i've found out this solution, that drift a lot form original code, but not so much from original concept, and also it is a lot clearer.

new (working) code:

```
private static int getMax(int[] values) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i+=1+maxLength) { // here we are looking for the first zero. if lenght remaining is lesser than actual max zero-strike, no way we caund found a better.

        if (values[i] == 0) { // is zero

            //find leftmost zero
            int tmpLeft = 0;
            while(tmpLeft < i && values[i-tmpLeft-1] == 0){
                tmpLeft++;
            }

            //find righmost zero
            int tmpRight = 0;
            while(tmpRight+i < values.length && values[i+tmpRight] == 0){
                tmpRight++;
            }

            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, tmpLeft+tmpRight);



        }
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

Also runned some benchmark versus OP code (random sample of value generated with values[a] = r.nextInt(3); ). (banchamrk full code: https://gist.github.com/MauroMombelli/b68641a785f3e93fd410)

for array of size == 10, op code is 2 time faster on this pc (1000 nanosec vs 2000 nanosec)

for array of size == 100 code execution are similar

for array == 1000 my code is faster, op code take fixed 5700 nanosec, my code from 3000 to 3500

for array == 1000, but value from 0 to 9, op code take fixed 3079nanosec, my code from 2200 to 2600

for array == 1000 (0-9) op code take 30.000-47.000 mine 10.000-13.000

old (not working) code:

```
public class ZeroSeriesLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = {1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0};

        int maxLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length-maxLength ; i++) { //here we are looking for the first zero. if lenght remaining is lesser than actual max zero-strike, no way we caund found a better.

            if (values[i] == 0) { //first zero
                int tmpCheck = i+maxLength+1;//shot for a streak with at least one more zero
                while (tmpCheck > i && values[tmpCheck] == 0){
                    tmpCheck--;
                }
                if (tmpCheck == i){ //true if those between i and i+maxLength+1 was all zero!
                    //we have a strike bigger than actual by at least 1!
                    maxLength++;
                    //now check for additional zero on the right, but please don't overflow
                    while(i + maxLength + 1 < values.length && values[i+maxLength+1] == 0){
                        maxLength++;
                    }
                }
                i+=maxLength+1; //no need to check again all that zero and last not-zero!
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Maximum number of consecutive zeros : " + maxLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm not convinced that the optimization is worth the complexity of iterating out of order. `values = { 0 }` → `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. `values = { 0, 0 }` → 1.

Comment: Code is untested, i may fix it later, buf the important is you get the idea. Optimization depends on need

Comment: If you can produce evidence that this performs > 15% faster on average I will upvote

Comment: challenge accepted, I'll try at home

Comment: This will pay off for large arrays with many zero streaks of varying length. Once you find a streak of twenty, you can skip ahead twenty slots. If many of the streaks you find going forward are short, you skip checking a lot of elements, but I don't see how the *average* could be anywhere near 15%. You still get a +1 for the trick though (useful in text searching too).

Comment: You might want to test this, I think it gives the wrong answer in the sample. This is when it finds and skips a shorter series of 0's it then jumps maxlength+1 which might put it in the middle of the next series of 0's

Comment: But it check if they was zero on the left, and if jm in the mixdle, i will still gain half jump. Imho bigger is the array, bigger is the gain

Comment: yee! @Cruncher here it is! updated with working code, almost 33% faster on array of 10.000 element!

Comment: @lesto Impressive. You've earned my vote. In real world applications, whether this will actually give the speed up or not depends on the general nature of the data that you know before hand. If 0's are scarce, then this is not worth it.

Comment: @Cruncher because in the "for" the increment is "i+=1+maxLength", unless you have a hig number of small dataset it is always worth on array of at least X elements (where empirically X is near 100), and more zero-streak are find early, more speed up is gained.

Even with only one zero, if it is one of the first element, you get almost half iteration. And for small dataset, the overhead of 1000nanosec (on a 2.33GHz cpu) is so small you can get over it.

Comment: @lesto small overheads can be big overheads if part of a much larger algorithm. I agree with you in general though. It's just always good to have consideration for possible data.

Answer (score 2):

I have thought of this:

```
public static int countSuccessive2(int[] values, int target) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    int tempLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        if (values[i] == target) {
            tempLength++;
        } else {
            tempLength = 0;

            if(values.length - i <= maxLength){
                break;
            }
        }

        if (tempLength > maxLength) {
            maxLength = tempLength;
        }
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

What I do above is: if I've just broken a chain and I already have a chain of, let's say, 5 zeroes, and my array has only 4 positions left to check, why check them? I can't get a bigger chain.

Maybe this time, with this little array of values, it doesn't matter, but in a bigger one with chains that have hundreds of target elements, it would matter.

What do you think?